# How to create Image grid with org mode for latex export

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm experimenting with org mode to write my reports. In the past year I've been working with latex and now I want to see how far I can go with the abstractions of org-mode. Hoping to write my thesis in it. So far it has been pushing back very hard, so maybe it isn't a good idea. Try to prove me wrong (if I am of course).

My question:
How can I create with org mode a grid of images. Or at least put two images next to each other (that would already be nice)

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form, you can directly insert image links into a table thus:

```
| [[./img1.jpg]] | [[./img2.jpg]] |
| [[./img3.jpg]] | [[./img4.jpg]] |
```

If you need finer control on the rendering, [check this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/84372) for an example where a macro is defined for wrapping image insertion code.